# C: tcp recv not clearing old data

Tags: c, sockets

I have the following code in server.c

```
while (1) {
    char msg[1024];
    recv(fd, msg, 1024, 0);
}
```

From client, first, I sent "hello world".

And then I received "hello world" in server.

I then sent "hexx" to server.

But I received "hexxo world" on server.

It seems as if msg wasn't cleared fully.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Cheers.

Comment: You are allocating 1024 bytes for message and never zeroing that data. You are just reading into the same buffer over and over. First pass it reads "hello world" in the second pass you are putting "hexx" in the same starting address resulting in "hexxo world"

Comment: @bentank thanks. It works. One question, is it always necessary to bzero the char array?

Comment: It is never necessary to bzero the char array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are allocating 1024 bytes for message and never zeroing that data. You are just reading into the same buffer over and over. First pass it reads "hello world" in the second pass you are putting "hexx" in the same starting address resulting in "hexxo world"

As DoxyLover mentions you can null terminate the newly read string and get what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`read()` does not null terminate the buffer. Therefore, you are seeing the old data left over in the buffer.

What you want is something like:

```
while (1) {
    char msg[1024];
    ssize_t n = recv(fd, msg, 1023, 0);
    if (n >= 0)
        msg[n] = '\0';
}
```

Note that I am limiting the read to one less than the size of the buffer to allow space for the null byte. Obviously, this only works with text data. With binary data, you need to record the return value from `read()` and use that as a byte count when processing the buffer. For example, to copy data from one socket to another:

```
while (1) {
    char msg[1024];
    ssize_t n = recv(fd, msg, 1024, 0);
    if (n > 0)
        send(second_fd, msg, n, 0);
}
```

All of this is very simplified - you need error checking, check the return from `read()` to make sure any bytes were received, check the return from `send()` to make sure all of the byte were sent, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> tcp recv not clearing old data

Who said it would? Not that it should be necessary. You're ignoring the count returned by `recv().` After calling `recv(),` there are three possibilities:

1. Return value of -1: an error; call `perror()`.
2. Return value of 0: end of stream: close the socket and exit the read loop.
3. Return value is positive: you have received exactly that many bytes into your buffer, and you should not assume that any data beyond that count is valid.

At present you're doing none of these things correctly.